# How to add data to a form without knowing form fields?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

First of all thanks to those who helped me a lot in my work. Guys I'm in a serious trouble now. Help me if you can.

I have a form in my database (field in HTML form) and even I don't know what caused the form to be dynamic, I'm calling that form in a view and I'm using the form to edit data in other columns of the database, so I'm retrieving those data through my controller. The problem is: How can I set the data in form?

Example form look like this:

```
<form-template>
    <fields>
        <field type="text" subtype="text" required="true" label="Title" class="form-control" name="title"/>
        <field type="textarea" required="true" label="Description" class="form-control" name="description"/>
        <field type="text" subtype="text" required="true" label="check" class="form-control" name="check"/>
        <field type="text" subtype="text" required="true" label="Location" class="form-control" name="location"/>
        <field type="file" label="Image" class="form-control file-input" name="image" multiple="true"/>
    </fields>
</form-template>
```

And my data is in JSON format looks like this as example:

```
{
    "fieldId": "3",
    "title": "Honda",
    "description": "test",
    "check": "test",
    "location": "Karachi",
    "image": [
        "Honda_0.jpg",
        "Honda_1.jpg",
        "Honda_2.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Please help me guys. My project is almost done and this was the last thing I have to do.

Comment: So you're facing problem to retrieve data from JSON ?

Comment: What have you tried already, what were your steps? That helps us focusing better on the actual answer.

Comment: You must identify each your field somehow

Comment: no bro retriving data from json is easy but setting data to form with knowing what kind of form is that?

Comment: only i have is the name of they field.

Comment: @jbehrens94 bro i dont know what to try on this .

Comment: bro, what is "setting data to form?"

Answer (score 0):

Get the JSON and put it in a variable.

Now for every input field you put a value to it,

```
<?php $title = your_json_field; ?>

<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title">
```

I think json_decode works for that, I'm not really good in json that's why I was not able to include it sorry,

But hope this helps you